# How to override spree controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I changed currency in spree ecommerce and now I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Spree::OrdersController#populate
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #116):


114        self.currency = currency
115        self.price    = variant.price_in(currency).amount +
116                        variant.price_modifier_amount_in(currency, opts)
117      else
118        self.price    = variant.price +
                        variant.price_modifier_amount(opts)
```

[image]

So I want to rewrite `OrdersController`
I read this:
https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/logic.html
But I am still confused - where can I find an initial  code for this orderscontroller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I changed currency in spree ecommerce and now I get the following error:

variant.price_modifier_amount_in(currency, opts) is definitely returning nil. So, the way you have changed the currency is breaking the system, try debug it.

> So I want to rewrite OrdersController
>   if you want to rewrite part of OrdersController, you should use deface https://github.com/spree/deface

For example you can add order_controller_decorator.rb to app/controllers/spree/
with the following code

```
def update
  if @order.contents.update_cart(order_params)
    respond_with(@order) do |format|
      format.html do
        if params.has_key?(:checkout)
          @order.next if @order.cart?
          redirect_to checkout_state_path(@order.checkout_steps.first)
        else
          redirect_to cart_path
        end
      end
    end
  else
    respond_with(@order)
  end
end
```

this code will change/override the update function only.

if you want to replace everything in the controller create orders_controller.rb file in app/controllers/spree/
and then add your code. you might want to take reference from [original source code for order_controller](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/frontend/app/controllers/spree/orders_controller.rb)

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the spree controller. The problem is that:

```
variant.price_modifier_amount_in(currency, opts)
```

is returning a `nil` instance. Which is why you get:

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: anyway, where can i get the code for this controller?

Comment: The stack trace you pasted into your question (on the first line) shows the path to the object throwing the error. Stack trace is your friend. Learn to love it.